# The number of triangles in the Cayley graph of a finite abelian group.

Tags: graph-theory, abelian-groups, characters

Let $G$ be finite abelian group of type $(m_1, \dots, m_d)$:
$G = \langle a_i \rangle \times \cdots \times \langle a_d \rangle$, where $|\langle a_i \rangle| = m_i$

And let $S \subseteq G$: $k = |S|$, $S = \{s_1, \dots, s_k\}$.
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
s_1 & = &  a_1^{k_{11}} \cdot a_2^{k_{12}} \dots a_d^{k_{1d}} \\ 
s_2 & = &  a_1^{k_{21}} \cdot a_2^{k_{22}} \dots a_d^{k_{2d}} \\ 
 & \dots \\
s_k & = &  a_1^{k_{k1}} \cdot a_2^{k_{k2}} \dots a_d^{k_{kd}} \\ 
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
It is convenient for me that the set $S$ is given by the $d \times k$  matrix $(K_{li}) = \frac{k_{li}}{m_i}$

Let $\Gamma$ be a Caley graph of group $G$ and generating set $S$. I want to count triangles in $\Gamma$.

Well know, that spectrum of this Caley graph is
${\rm Spec}(\Gamma) = \{\chi_i(S) | i=1,\dots,n\}$, where $\chi(S) = \sum_{s\in S}\chi(s).$ Thus, number of triangles $\Delta(\Gamma)$ is
$$
\Delta(\Gamma) = \frac{1}{6} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \chi_i(S)^3
$$

There is a canonical bijection between the set of characters $\{\chi_i \}$ and $G$.

If $a \in G$ and $a = a_1^{x_1} \cdots a_d^{x_d}$, $\zeta_i$ be a primitive $m_i$-th root ofunity, then we can define 
$$
\chi_{a}(a_1^{y_1} \cdots a_d^{y_d})= \chi_{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_d}(a_1^{x_1} \cdots a_d^{x_d}) =\zeta_1^{x_1 y_1} \cdots \zeta_d^{x_d y_d}
$$
And
$$
\Delta(\Gamma) =\frac{1}{6} \sum\limits_{x_1 = 1}^{m_1} \sum\limits_{x_2=1}^{m_2} \cdots \sum\limits_{x_d=1}^{m_d} \left(\sum_{l = 1}^k \zeta_1^{x_1 k_{l1}} \cdots \zeta_d^{x_d k_{ld}}\right)^3
$$
By
$$
\zeta_1^{x_1 k_{l1}} \cdots \zeta_d^{x_d k_{ld}} = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m_1}x_1k_{1l}} \cdots e^{\frac{2i\pi}{m_d}x_dk_{dl}}
$$
and
$$
{\frac{2i\pi}{m_1}x_1k_{1l}} + \cdots +{\frac{2i\pi}{m_d}x_dk_{dl}} = 2i\pi\sum\limits_{i=1}^d \frac{x_i k_{li}}{m_i}
$$
Finally we get
$$
\Delta(\Gamma) =\frac{1}{6} \sum\limits_{x_1 = 1}^{m_1} \sum\limits_{x_2=1}^{m_2} \cdots \sum\limits_{x_d=1}^{m_d} \left( e^{2\pi i F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)},  1_k \right)^3
$$
where $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)$ is vector-valued function $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d) = K\cdot {\rm x}$, ${\rm x} = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)^{T}$, $1_k$ - all-$1$ vector, and $(\cdot, \cdot)$ - dot product.

This formula looks awful, can it be simplified? For example, using additionally that $S^{-1} = S$.

Is it possible to get a nontrivial upper bound of triangles number in terms of $m_i$ and $|S|$?

Is it possible to get simple criteria that $\Gamma$ is triangle free?